# async returns future of void type instead of expected type

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm learning C++'s futures and asynchronous programming. I have the following code based on that in chapter 42 of Stroustrup's C++ reference. Both GCC and Microsoft compilers complain that there is no conversion from `future<void>` to `future<InputIterator>`in the call to `push_back`. Why is the call to async returning a `future<void>` instead of a `future<std::iterator>` that I would expect from `std::find`?

```
template<typename T, typename InputIter>
InputIter p_find(InputIter first, InputIter last, const T& value, const int grain)
{
    std::vector<std::future<InputIter>> results;
    while (first != last)
    {
        results.push_back(std::async([=]() mutable {std::find(first, first + grain, value); }));
        first += grain;
    }
    //blah blah
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your lambda returns nothing (that is `void`), so the result of `async()` is `std::future<void>`. What you want is probably

```
results.push_back(std::async([=]() mutable {return std::find(first, first + grain, value); }));
//                                          ^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks. That did it. Compiles in MSVC 2013 now.